# I'm making a centipede clone - how to code move logic that only moves each segment a few pixels

Tags: godot

I'm making an arcade Centipede game clone and would like to know if there is a way to emulate the snake style move, and importantly, the move needs to be just a few pixels rather than in chars/blocks. I've seen logic where you take the last section of the snake and use that to create a new head but those examples are based on blocks/chars rather than pixels. I want to move the centipede by just a few pixels each move.

Is there a way of moving the centipede based around the head segment rather than assigning a movement vector to each segment of the snake. And each time the move code runs the whole centipede has only moved a couple of pixels?

I'm not after actual code, just a explanation/overview/pseudo code would be a huge help to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For continuous movement in a snake-like game, you can represent it as a list of segments.

Advancing would increase the length the head segment in the same direction, and reduce the length of the tail. When the length of the tail reaches 0, that segment is removed, and the next segment is now the tail. And you make sure to keep the length consistent.

Changing direction would involve adding a new segment at the head in the new direction.

This approach also has the advantage of not being limited to a fixed set of angles.

To show it, each segment is an object. Rotated and stretched to match the end points of the segment. You can use extra sprites for head and tail.

---

However, for a game like the classic Atari centipede, I would just have a series of sprites, and well… Move them a few pixel each frame.